# PHP function return value - don't know how to proceed..!

Tags: php

I'm a newbie and struggling with PHP - I've read and searched but I just can't work out the following exercise:-

Declare a function which has two arguments. Inside the function add the two numbers and return the result.

In the main part of the PHP script:

Create two variables and assign the first a value of 3 and the second a value of 4.

While the first variable is less than 6 repeat the following (loop):

Call the function using the two variables as arguments.

Capture the value returned from the function.
Print the result of the return value.
Increment the value of the first variable.
End the loop

This is what I have so far:-

```
<?php
function stock($order,$onhand){
echo "Order $order <br> On Hand $onhand <br>";
}
stock("3","17");

function sum($x,$y) {
$z=$x+$y;
return $z;
}
echo "3 + 17 = " . sum(3,17) . "<br>";
?>
<br>

<?php
$x=3;
$y=4;
$z=$x+$y;
echo $z;
?>
```

I would really appreciate some guidance thanks.

Comment: you dont seem to be using any loops there!

Comment: Have a tea break here :
http://www.homeandlearn.co.uk/php/php5p1.html and http://www.tizag.com/phpT/forloop.php

Comment: Can you just tell what you are trying to do ? Expected output and your inputs ?

Comment: What's your main goal there?

Comment: Take a look at the `while()` example #2 in the php docs - http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.while.php. It looks like you need to do the same thing, but instead of echoing the `$i`, you need to echo your `sum()` function. Note, the syntax in example 1 - `while(exp){...}` is often more used/accepted the the syntax in example 2 - `while(exp): ... endwhile;`

Comment: Thanks for the comments - As for those asking the Expected output & my inputs or my goals - I've copied the exercise exactly as it was given to me - and, I've commenced the exercise but basically I don't know how to finish it.